# ListView from 2 tables

Tags: android, listview, cursor

I have 2 tables.
In the first table I have news (for example: 2 fields 'id' and 'text').
In the second table I have images, that attached to news (for example: 'id', 'new_id', 'src').

There are more than one image for one news. How can fill ListView with such data?

Answer (score 0):

this is how I think of it: 
first of all, create a DTO (Data transfer object) for each table;
then, create the layout that represents the list's cell.
you'll need to create a custom adapter, and here is how you can do it http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#ownadapter.
and the last thing is to extract your data from the database and pass it to your adapter.

this link http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html explains what I said in a clear way and in more details.

hoe this helps.